# Temperature of degenerate quantum gas

Tags: thermodynamics

In a recent test, I came across the following question:

> What is the approximate average temperature of a degenerate quantum
>   gas of *N* quantum particles (not charged) with mass *m* bound in the
>   volume *V*? The particles have no internal degrees of freedom.

How do I go about solving this problem? I have trouble finding a starting point in this case. Does it matter here if the particles are bosons or fermions? Since the particles are not charged, there is at least no electric contribution to the potential, and the only potential the particles feel is that they are trapped in *V*.

Comment: Maybe a very poorly phrased question? Could they be asking for the Fermi temperature as a function of mass and particle density? Or the average kinetic energy over the free-electron band?

Comment: @Pieter That is a possibility indeed..the degeneracy is confusing me, and also that it is not specified which type of quantum particle it is.

Comment: It is a horrible question. A degenerate quantum gas has $T= 0$ in first approximation. And temperature is not defined for a single particle, it does not make much sense to ask for average temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approximate temperature of a degenerate quantum gas is zero. That is the meaning of "degenerate" in this context.

Comment: Thank you very much! How does the mass and the enclosed volume come into higher order corrections?

Comment: @andynitrox I am sure one could calculate temperature from internal energy for quantum gases, but it is not a standard problem, I have never seen it. Was this from a solid-state physics test? At what level?

Comment: It was a revision course in general quantum mechanics for first-year Master students. Hence I was also expecting a more or less straight-forward solution.

Comment: @andynitrox Then I would regard $N, m, V$ as distractors. Creative question, but too mean; I will never use it in my exams. And even then: poorly phrased because of "average". The alternative interpretation is stupidity of the examiner.

Comment: Alright then, thank you for the answer! The question sounded to me like the equivalent of "What is the temperature?" without necessary additional information ^^

Answer (score 0):

According to the lecturer, the correct answer would have been as follows:

The total energy of a quantum particle without potential is given by its kinetic energy $\frac{p^2}{2m}$ where $p$ is the momentum. Since the particle is bound in the volume $V$, the expectation value of the momentum $\langle p \rangle$ is zero and $p$ is given by $\Delta p = \frac{\hbar}{2} \frac{1}{\Delta x}$ through the Heisenberg Uncertainty relation. The equals sign here means that the gas is a *degenerate* quantum gas; for a non-degenerate quantum gas the uncertainty product $\Delta x \Delta p$ is larger than $\frac{\hbar}{2}$.

From then we proceed:

$$\Delta x = \Big(\frac{V}{N}\Big)^{1/3}$$
where $N$ is the number of particles in volume $V$.
$$\Delta p = p = \frac{\hbar}{2} \Big(\frac{N}{V}\Big)^{1/3}$$
and we can find an expression for the kinetic energy of the gas:
$$E_{kin} = \frac{\hbar^2}{8m} \Big(\frac{V}{V}\Big)^{2/3}$$
this can be evaluated by using the caloric equation and rearranged for $T$.

$$E_{kin} = E_{therm} = \frac{3}{2} k_B T$$
$$T = \frac{\hbar^2}{12m k_B} \Big(\frac{N}{V}\Big)^{2/3}$$

Comment: The thermal energy of a degenerate gas is not $3Nk_B T/2$, it is $\sim 0$.